# how to increase the size of text in radio button and it should be aligned center

Tags: html, css

```css
.big{ width: 2.5em; height: 1.5em; }
```

```html
<p>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="a" checked="checked" class="big" />
<span>Closed</span>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="b" class="big" />
<span>Pending</span>
</p>
```

Now the text is coming down near the Radio button but it want the text should be in the center.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8865463/4185106

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this css

```
.big{ width: 2.5em;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
.align{height: 1.5em;}
.text-big{ font-size:1.2em}
.span{
   display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
```

`https://jsfiddle.net/tkp2007p/1/`

Comment: K fine,inside the checked="checked" the background color should be yellow is it possible?

Comment: glad it helped. Well I have tried a lot for that in past but could found a solution. At last settled with toggle effect with images for checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vertical align` for this.

```css
.big{ width: 2.5em; height: 1.5em; }
p span,
p .big{vertical-align: middle}
```

```html
<p>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="a" checked="checked" class="big" />
<span>Closed</span>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="b" class="big" />
<span>Pending</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .align{line-height: 1.5em;}
    .big{ width: 2.5em; }
    .text-big{ font-size:1.2em}
```

```html
 <p>
    <span class="align">

       <input type="radio" name="r1" value="a" checked="checked" class="big" />
       <span class="text-big">Closed</span>

       <input type="radio" name="r1" value="b" class="big" />
       <span class="text-big">Pending</span>

    </span>
    </p>
```

> Here I wrapped the entire `radio` and its `text` in a span with class `align`
>   And added `line-height` to that class.

Comment: @Atula , what you mean, check the fiddle .

Comment: where you have added line-height property?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<p>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="a" checked="checked" class="big" />
<span>Closed</span>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="b" class="big" />
<span>Pending</span>
</p>
```

css:

```
.big{ width: 2.5em; height: 1.5em; }

.big+span{
  font-size:15px;
}

.big ,.big+span{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[https://jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/PrabuB/5mjLt4ag/2/)

updated as per your request:

```
<p>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="a" checked="checked" class="big" id="r1" />
<label for="r1">Closed</label>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="b" class="big"  id="r2"/>
<label for="r2">Pending</label>
</p>
```

css:

```
/* COMMON RADIO STYLES  */

input[type=radio]{
  /* hide original inputs */
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
input[type=radio] + label{
  cursor:pointer;
}
input[type=radio] + label:before{
  height:16px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  content: " ";
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 6px #e4e4e4;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* CUSTOM RADIO STYLES */

input[type=radio] + label:before{
  border-radius:50%;
  width:16px;
}

/* CHECKED */
input[type=radio]:checked + label:before{
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 3px #e4e4e4, inset 0 0 1px #222, inset 0 0 0 3px yellow;
 background:#000;
    }
```

output:

[https://jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/PrabuB/5mjLt4ag/5/)

Comment: inside the checked="checked" the background color should be yellow is it possible?